# Malformed byte sequence: “a9”

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1ab0e88673.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        
        <div class="top">
            <img src="./static/images/PngItem_5002858.png" alt="image for chatbot" id="img1">
            <h2 id="amh">Ask my HR</h2>
            <button type="submit" id="reload"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt" ></i></button>
            <button type="submit" id="exit"><i class="fas fa-times-circle" ></i></button>
            
        </div>
        <hr id="hrone">

        <div class="section">
                <div class="question" id="question_3">
                    <label id="ques1_lab">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</label>
                </div>
                <div id="answer_3">
                    <div class="container" id="ans3_lorem1">
                        <label class="ans3_head">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing simply Ipsum is simply</label>
                        <p class="ans3_p">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br>printing and 
                            typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum<br>has been the industry's 
                            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s<a></a> </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container" id="ans3_lorem2">
                        <label class="ans3_head">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing simply Ipsum is simply</label>
                        <p class="ans3_p">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br>printing and 
                            typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum<br>has been the industry's 
                            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <input type="text" name="question" id="ask" placeholder="Ask Something ? "> 
            <button type="submit" id="send_btn"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="end">
            <span id="copy_ele">©</span>
            <h6 id="last_tag">Powered by CogniCor</h6>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Tried building a chatbot project with HTML and CSS.When I tried to validate the Html it send me an error like " Malformed byte sequence: “a9”.At line 50, column 33". Please help me. I would also like to know what all count as good practice when using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Good practice is knowing and using your character encodings correctly.

Comment: Replace the copyright symbol at the bottom with `&copy;`

Answer (score 0):

It is something related to use copyright symbol directly in the HTML. So just replace your code

```
<span id="copy_ele">©</span>
```

with the following code.

```
<span id="copy_ele">&#169;</span>
```

Hope this will help you.